# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor on CRAN Debian builds

Tags: r, debian, r-package, cran

Just a quick preface, I have looked into all the other stackoverflow comments I can find related to this error and cannot still correct or identify my issue based on existing posts.

I am currently having an issue getting past a warning that's occurring on linux based builds for my vignette.  The warning is:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

The check results are here:
https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/DEVis_1.0.1_20181220_164555/Debian/00check.log

Windows and OS X builds work fine, but I don't have access to a debian machine that I can reproduce this on.  I currently cannot reproduce this issue on my side, and travis-ci checks do not seem to produce this warning for linux on ubuntu.  I can only see it currently when submitting an update to my package and failing the [cran](/questions/tagged/cran) auto-checks.

I have recently changed from PDF vignette to html-based, and am not sure why [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) packages would even be loading in this case.  I have attempted to correct for it based on [this post](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/274), which claims the issue is a conflict between kableExtra and xcolor.

Some relevant sections of code from the vignette might include:

````
vignette: |
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{DEVis} 
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
  %\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
---


```{r loadData, echo = F, eval = TRUE}
#load("../data/exampleData.Rda")
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ='../vignettes/')`
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
             cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
             fig.align='center',
             external=TRUE,
             echo=TRUE,
             warning=FALSE,
             fig.pos='H'
            )
a4width<- 8.3
a4height<- 11.7

library(kableExtra)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
````

The full package code can be found here: https://github.com/price0416/DEvis

I would appreciate any insight anyone can offer into this issue, as I cannot update my package until I get to the bottom of this!  Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer is to remove the following lines:

```
 %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 %\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

These are LaTeX lines apparently and on debian cran builds are causing the above problem.